# typeof equivalent in scriptsharp

Tags: script#

I have some exisiting code in javascript:

> function setPostData(selector, data) {
>
> if (typeof(data) === 'function')
> data = data();
>
> $(selector).setParam({'postData':data});
>
> }

how would this translate to scriptsharp (0.7)? esp the **if** statement...
the function accepts data parameter, which can be a dictionary or a function returning a dictionary.
if data is a function, this function should be called first, returning a dictionary result...

splitting the function in two function is not the recommended solution, because it is called from other javascript (non scriptsharp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if (Type.GetScriptType(data) == "function")
{
    Func<object> dataAsFunctor = (Func<object>)data;
    data = dataAsFunctor();
}
```